# How to have both the click and get the id in the same method which causes a issue

Tags: java, selenium

I have a method where I fetch the id and also get the `latestid` and append it to the **url**.

The Problem is since I have both the click and get `latestid` in the same method it leads to stale.

element when I try to append the id to the URL.

Since the same method needs to be used in different screens where in one method I need to click on

the ID and the other Method I need to append the URL, I wanted both this in the same method and

call this method wherever required.

**Below is my code:**

```
public static HashMap<String, String> Value; 

public static void GetId(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {

        String PBtnElem = planningbuttonXpath_Replace.replace("XXXX", "confirm");
        clickOnButton(driver, PBtnElem );

        HashMap<String, String> Value = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        List<WebElement> tableValues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span"));
        int tableValueSize = tableValues.size();
        System.out.println("Get the no of rows:"+tableValueSize);

        WebElement latestId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span)["+tableValueSize +"]"));
        System.out.println("Latest ids: "+ latestId .getText());
        Value.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()); 
        System.out.println(Value.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()));
```

I use the above method in two places below is the code:

```
public static boolean plan(WebDriver driver)  
    {
        {
            try {

                GetId(driver); // I am using it here that is I am, using the above method here I fetch the id and click on the Id the Click Action happens in this screen 
                return true;

            }catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

And  i use the same method to call the id and append it to the url:

Below is the method:

```
  public static boolean acceptprop(WebDriver driver, Map<String, String> formEntryMap){
     try{

    String pendingconfirmBtnElem = buttonXpath_Replace.replace("XXXX", "PENDING CONFIRMATION");
    clickOnButton(driver, PendingConfirmationBtnElem);
            
            
    String confirmationURL = "https://test.app.net/#/email?type=proposal";
    List<String> newurls = new ArrayList<String>();

    GetId(driver); // This is the place where I call that method again
            
    newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + Value.get("latestDataId")); //this is the place where I append the id to the URL

    driver.get(newurls.get(0));
    return true;
    }
   catch (InterruptedException iex) {
            return false;
        }
 }
```

**StackTrace:**

> rg.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
> reference: element is not attached to the page document   (Session
> info: chrome=92.0.4515.159) For documentation on this error, please
> visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

**Can i get more inputs **

I want to have the same method where i can use it to click as well

as use it to append the id to the url

Comment: Assuming `clickOnButton` does the click, it happens before any `findElement`, so there shouldn't be any `StaleElementReferenceException`. I also don't see any navigation using the ID you extracted. Please post the full code that causing the issue and the stacktrace.

Comment: @Guy updated the code in the question with the places where iam using ths method

Comment: @Guy when i remove the .click it works fine when i append the id to the url in the last method but before that i need to do a click in another screena and hence cannot remove the click method

Comment: Added Stack Trace as well any leads?

Comment: all the methods are static in nature, so when the class loads, they all get loaded/executed before any object. What is the sequence you are having for these 3 methods ? also put system.out.println before and after of each line in these methods and see which one got printed and which did not.

Comment: Sequence: There are 3 tabs in the same screen  1)Tab 1 - Open 2)Tab 2-Pending 3)Tab 3- Confirm  My Sequence - I get the lastest id from the tab 1  and then i Navigate to Tab 2  read the table in Tab 2 and then click on the Id and  after the id is clicked it will go to the Edit plan Screen where i click on the Send Proposal button .2) After send proposal i navigate back to the pending tab and read the table take the lastest id and  i need to append the lastestid to the url and navigate to the accept screen in order to accept the plan

Comment: this is the Sequence as you see in the first case i need to click on the id and in the second case i need to only append the id to the url

Comment: Adding some more: I did  a sysout for the getid method and is fetching the id properly and also in the other 1st methods it is getting the id properly but third method not able to get the id bz of stale element

Comment: @cruisepandey hope i have given a clarity on what you are asking for

Comment: @sandy : When ever you reply to individuals always use @. otherwise we do not get the notifications. Now, I think issue lies here `After send proposal i navigate back to the pending tab ` since you come back to the 2nd page, by the time you come back elements becomes stale. you need to define the web element again and then continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: @cruisepandey:you mean in GetId method? i need to enter the same script ?WebElement latestId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span)["+tableValueSize +"]"));
        System.out.println("Latest ids: "+ latestId .getText());
        Value.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()); 
        System.out.println(Value.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()));

Comment: Whenever you are navigating back to the old screen from where you went to any new screen, that's exactly where you have to redefine the elements. so that they don't become stale.

Comment: @cruisepandey :public static boolean acceptprop method i call Getid(driver) method so i should call this again after this line .... newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + Value.get("latestDataId")); //this is the place where I append the id to the URL and get the issue

Comment: It's difficult to read in comment section, your code. Please do that as mention and put system.out.println and see if you are getting all the necessary output

Comment: @cruisepandey - let me revert

Comment: in the 3rd method that i have posted in the question. 1st) in the first method i.e. GetID(driver) i have the lastestid.click() and when i call the GetiD method in the public static boolean acceptprop - method it clicks on the lastestid which i dont want and as a result of which it is not able to append the id to the url and leads to stale element exception - @cruisepandey

Comment: what i can understand is that there needs to be somemodification made in the GETID method where in it should click the id only when it is required otherwise it should fetch the lastestid but not sure how to deal with this

Comment: @Tal Angel - This is the issue which i was relating to in the other post ...

Comment: @sandy : `what i can understand is that there needs to be somemodification made in the GETID method where in it should click the id only when it is required otherwise it should fetch the lastestid but not sure how to deal with this` - This sounds good, try it out !

Comment: Can Any body else can give inputs on this please